# Направление движения свайпа

Tags: javascript, swipe

Я начал делать меню, чтобы при свайпе влево, открывалось меню, а при свайпе вправо закрывалось. Но я не понимаю, как мне определять продолжительность свайпа и направление движения. Я нашёл свойство `timeStamp`, я думаю это как-то связано со временем, но оно выдаёт непонятные цифры, не понимаю что они значат. Подскажите

```js
document.addEventListener('touchmove', (event) => {
 console.log(event);
});
```

Comment: а зачем определять продолжительность?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ если долгий свайп, то не открывать меню. Т.к. это может быть случайное касание

Comment: @StrangerintheQ если знаете как, покажите маленький пример. Возможно моя логика в корне неверная

Comment: https://raw.githack.com/strangerintheq/collect-the-dots/master/index.html

Comment: https://github.com/strangerintheq/collect-the-dots/blob/master/TouchControls.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так?

```js
let x = null;
document.addEventListener('touchstart', e => x = e.touches[0].clientX);
document.addEventListener('touchmove', e => {
    if (!x) return;
    x = x - e.touches[0].clientX < 0 ? 0 : -90;
    test.style.transform = `translate(${x}%,0)`;
    x = null;
});
```

```css
#test {
  transition: 0.5s;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background: wheat;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">menu example<br>swipe left to hide</div>
```

Comment: Да, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Версия для PCшников

> зажать и потащить

```js
let lastPos;
let menu = document.querySelector(".menu");

window.addEventListener("mousedown", e => {
  lastPos = e.clientX;
  window.addEventListener("mousemove", showMenu);
});

function showMenu(e){
  if(event.buttons == 0){
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", showMenu);
  }else {
    menu.style.width = (e.clientX > lastPos) ? "100px" : "0px";
  }
}
```

```css
.menu{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: cyan;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
</div>
```